# How to get reasonably formated text tables out of excel for use as plain text or Markdown

Tags: excel, text, format

I had the following situation:

Spreadsheet used to calculate pricing for a bunch of different kinds of trees.  (I'm a tree farmer)

This data has two uses:

1. I use it in Markdown to make tables on my web page.
2. I use it in kijiji ads.

The latter made things sticky.  Cut and paste from excel leaves data separated by single tabs.  Nothing lines up.  A pasted table in excel in some program like Kijiji looks like this:

```
|   Bareroot Bundles of 25 2-3 year olds                            ||||
|   Bundles |   # Trees |   Cost    |   Price Per Tree  |
|:  -------------   :|: ------- :|: ------- :|: ------------------- :|
|   5 Trees |   5   |   $30.00  |   $6.00   |
|   Single Bundle   |   25  |   $75.00  |   $3.00   |
|   5 Bundles   |   125 |   $300.00 |   $2.40   |
|   10 Bundles  |   250 |   $525.00 |   $2.10   |
```

Yuck.

Comment: Hey site-Nazi's: this is exactly my question- I would like an answer. It seems perfectly on topic to me.

Comment: I would answer this properly, but the site-Nazi's closed it: I found this site: http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables    I was able to copy my from excel right into the grid and generate markdown table. Just what I needed.

Answer (score 6):

If I have a table like this:

[image]

I would do it with the following steps:

1. Add the header separators from a new row using a bunch of `-`, making sure that there is more than than less:

   [image]
2. Insert additional columns to contain the column separators, then select the cells that will have the separators. Insert the separator and then, instead of pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I would press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to fill all the selected cells at the same time:

   [image]
3. Format everything to the font Courier New, adjust the alignments and column widths:

   [image]
4. Save as Formatted Text:

   [image]

This will look like this if you open the file in notepad:

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Downsides from my persective: A.  I can't cut and paste a chunk as needed from the spreadsheet.  B:  I would have to create each product as a separate spreadsheeet.  As it is, these tidbits are on one sheet in a larger workbook.  C:  PRN files use carriage returns instead of newlines. D:  Using the Save As feature has gotten me in trouble on several occasions when I relied on more advanced features.  But the tip on space delimited file is one I'd missed.  This is a good additional recipe.

Comment: Another problem, specific to my use:  The colons are significant for use in markdown. They affect how markdown will center/justify columns. Spaces are not allowed in this row.  First round of playing with it, I was unable to get pipes to line up, and get a colon on the left side of a pipe, and eliminate spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple recipes for using excel data.

- Layout your spreadsheet as normal.
- Insert a blank row for the formating row.
- Create a wide column to the right of your table

Each row corresponding to a table row has a formula something like this:

```
"|"&A1&"|"&B1&"|"&C1...
```

The pipe symbols are for markdown, but also serve as cell boundary markers.

You will need to modify for possible grouping.  E.g. A one line title on a 5 column table will end up being

```
"|"&A1&"||||"
```

In the blank cell corresponding to the formatting row, type an appropriate string of |:--------:|...

My problem was a bit messier than that.  I advertise on Canada kijiji (not the same as the US version)  They allow some formatting in ads but do not have a table format at all.

I needed as ascii text table.  The results of cut and paste from excell into a text processor are less than stellar, as data is separated with a single tab character.  Anything that lines up is coincidence.

My route was to take this notion one step further, and make an ascii formated column that would work for either MMD or for text base ads.

First attempt:

```
"|" & A1 & REPT(" ",15-LEN(A1)) &
"|" & B1 &...
```

I didn't like the hard coding of the column widths.
And if your source column is $2.50 it comes across as 2.5

Second attempt.

1 blank column for each column I want to use.

If our table is 5 columns wide, I need another 5 columns.  Let's suppose the data I want is columns A-E.  I will create F-J for formatting.

F1 in this one has the formula

```
=TEXT(A1,"$0.00")
```

Replicate across and down as needed.  If the source text is already a string, it doesn't matter, it will come across unchanged.

Secondly, insert a row above.  In this row, but the column width you want for the output.

Now your formula for K2 will look like this:
"|" & F1 & REPT(" ",K$1-LEN(F1)) &
"|" & G1 ...

At this point if I want flush right text, I have to reverse
the REPT and the Cell reference.  No thoughts of centering.

The end result is this

```
|Bareroot Bundles of 25 2-3 year olds                      ||||
|Bundles             |# Trees   |      Cost| Price Per Tree|
|:-------------------|:---------|---------:|--------------:|
|5 Trees             |5         |    $30.00|          $6.00|
|Single Bundle       |25        |    $75.00|          $3.00|
|5 Bundles           |125       |   $300.00|          $2.40|
|10 Bundles          |250       |   $525.00|          $2.10|
```

In use, then I can cut and paste from my spread sheet, and just clip off the extra pipe symbols on the right edge of the top row.